# Проблема с UI-Тестом на android

Tags: java, android, ui

Я делаю UI-тест для своего приложения. Приложения делает следующие - пользователь вводит слова, например - Hello World, и исключения, например- Ho. И оно выдает - Hlleo dolrW. Ну то есть, инвертирует символы не исключения.

> UI-Test:

```
package com.example.mylesson_01;

import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;


import static androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;
import static androidx.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;



public class AglorithmUiTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> activityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void greeterSaysHello() {
        onView(withId(R.id.UserInput)).perform(typeText("Hello World"));
        onView(withId(R.id.enteringException)).perform(typeText("Ho"));
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        onView(withText(R.id.stringOne)).check(matches(withText("Hlleo dolrW")));
    }
}
```

> Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mylesson_01"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
```

> Когда я пытаюсь запустить тест, то выдаются вот эти ошибки -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
    at android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:44)
    at android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(InstrumentationRegistry.java:82)
    at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:144)
    at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:120)
    at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:103)
    at com.example.mylesson_01.AglorithmUiTest.<init>(AglorithmUiTest.java:20)
```

Использую эмулятор - Pixel_4a_API_30.
Анимации я отключил, сижу уже 5 час не понимаю в чем проблема. Прочитал много статей, так и не нашел решения свой проблемы, буду благодарен если поможете

Comment: в где `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` на классе?

Comment: Я его добавлял, он не помогает